# How should I pronounce 't' followed by 'the'?

Tags: pronunciation

This combination is really hard to me. This is an example:

> Knowing what to check is **just the** start to process.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I find myself not pronouncing the "t" in the word "just" when I read the sentence you have written. The next word "the" is pronounced properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In many (most?) dialects in both the US and the UK, "**just the**" would in normal speech would be pronounced [**ʤʌsðə**] before a consonant, or [**ʤʌsðiː**] before a vowel. That is, the 't' would be [elided](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision).

Comment: Upvoting because I'm one of the *many (most?)*, not because I actually know and agree that *either* word is correct (for all I know, it should really be **a few**! :)

Comment: Hi, how do you type those characters in square brackets?

Comment: @Yousui Those are IPA, [International Phonetic Alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) symbols. I use an [online IPA keyboard](http://weston.ruter.net/projects/ipa-chart/view/keyboard/) like [one of these](http://ipa.typeit.org/full/).

Comment: I would not say that the /t/ is totally unpronounced, e.g. in "a big *loss the* previous year" vs. "she *lost the* love of her life", the /t/ in 'lost' would be realized as a brief glottal stop or  pause in the frication of the [s] before the [ð] begins, whereas in *loss the* the [s] would glide directly into [ð] without any pause.

Comment: @Nohat this is an interesting point and I don't entirely disagree, but I'm not sure this is true or just a perception issue. We'd have to examine sonograms to be sure, I suppose.

Comment: Either way, for a non-native the guidance to elide it is not bad, I would venture; brief glottal stops or changes in frication or stridency are hard to learn or teach.

Comment: It's normal Fast Speech Rules for the /-t-/ in a /-stð-/ cluster to disappear, since you can't move your tongue from sibilant alveolar /s/ to interdental fricative /ð/ without passing through dental /t/ territory. So, don't bother to try and pronounce it just because it's spelled that way. That way likes Cholmondeley and Madness.

Comment: @Mark Beadles I do really wish there were a free resource like COCA with phonetic data that would enable a quick and dirty analysis.

Answer (score 4):

It's quite normal to omit a sound in this and in similar combinations of words. It's called *elision*.